# How to insert into a snowflake variant field using a DAO?

Tags: dao, jdbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following code:

```
@RegisterMapper(MyEntity.ResultMapper.class)
@UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator
public interface MyDao {

    @Transaction(TransactionIsolationLevel.SERIALIZABLE)
    @SqlBatch("INSERT INTO mySchema.myTable (" +
        " id, entity_type, entity_id, flags " +
        " ) VALUES " +
        "(" +
        " :stepId , :entityType , :entityId,parse_json(:flags) " +
        ")")
    @BatchChunkSize(500)
    Object create( @BindBean List<MyEntity> entities );
}
```

As you can see, I am bulk inserting a list of entities into my Snowflake table using this DAO.

The issue is that I am unable to insert into the flags columns, which is a variant. I have tried `to_variant(:flags)` and currently `parse_json(:flags)`, but the JDBI keeps throwing the following error:

```
net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL 
compilation error:
Invalid expression [PARSE_JSON(?)] in VALUES clause 
[statement:"INSERT INTO mySchema.myTable ( id, entity_type, 
entity_id, flags  ) VALUES ( :stepId , :entityType , :entityId,
parse_json(:flags) )", located:"null", rewritten:"null",
arguments:{ positional:{}, named:{timeStamp:'null', 
entityType:MYENTITY,
flags:'{"client":"myClient","flow":"myFlow"}',stepId:null, 
entityId:'189643357241513', class:class myOrg.MyEntity}, finder:[]}]
```

How should I pass the value in the flags column ? Has anyone attempted this before? The `flags` field in MyEntity is in my control, I can keep it as a POJO or a String, whichever helps me resolve this issue.

Comment: Try rewriting your insert stmt as smth like: INSERT INTO T SELECT parse_json(:flag);

Comment: @JianshengHuang, thanks a lot Sir. This worked. Why don't you post it as an answer ?

Comment: @JianshengHuang, will the new insert query work with SqlBatch as well? It seems to me that now for my list of 250 entities, inserts are happening one at a time.

Comment: You are encountering the current behavior that we don't support batch/array bind today for any DML other than INSERT INTO T VALUES (). Please file a support ticket with Snowflake if this is critical for your business for us to prioritize.

Comment: @JianshengHuang, well we moved to RDS anyway. But could the library throw an exception or let the caller know somehow that the SqlBatch annotation is not working because of the unsupported insert query ?

Answer (score 4):

See [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56784193/how-to-insert-into-a-snowflake-variant-field-using-a-dao/58513714#comment100177963_56784193) by Jiansheng Huang for answer:

```sql
INSERT INTO T SELECT parse_json(:flag);
```

Comment: Can also additional fields be used along?

Comment: Yes: https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc/issues/205