# batch-array bind not supported for Variant column

Tags: jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to batch insert 1000 records into Snowflake table. One of the column (entity) in my table (T1) is a Variant. This is setting the "arrayBindSupported" = false, which is resulting in 1000 single inserts.

SnowflakePreparedStatementV1.executeBatch() -> statementMetaData.isArrayBindSupported()

Insert query - "INSERT INTO T1 (id, name, TIMESTAMP, entity) SELECT ?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::TIMESTAMP_NTZ, PARSE_JSON(?)"

Is this batch + Variant insert supported in Snowflake jdbc ?? I see a similar issue reported in past, but not sure if this was ever implemented. [Other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56784193/how-to-insert-into-a-snowflake-variant-field-using-a-dao/58513714#comment100495409_56784193)

Comment: As far as I can see it's not supported. It's only supported for INSERTs under format: **INSERT INTO <table> VALUES (?,?)** and you can't use PreparedStatement to bind an array in this mode.